# How to parse csv unbound columns into map?

Tags: java, opencsv

I have an object with several bound fields (@CsvBindByName),
but I want to parse dynamic info into it.
So, i think about parse unbound fields into map [headerName -> valueOfColumn], How am i suppose to do it?